# OOP classes design: two numbers calculator

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

The problem is that write a two numbers calculator(+,-,*,/) using OOP. Based on intuition(I haven't learned design pattern yet), I wrote the code like this:

```cpp
class Calculator {  
  public:
    double calculate(double a, char op, double b) {
        switch (op) {
        case '+':
            ...   
        }
   }
```

However, my friend said it did't follow the `OCP` and he then showed me the following code:

```cpp
class Operator {
    virtual double eval(double a, double b) = 0;
}

class Add : public Operator {
    double eval(double a, double b) { 
        return a + b;
    }
}
...
class Calculator {
  public:
    Calculator() {
        Operator* add = new Add();
        Operator* sub = new Sub();
        Operator* mul = new Mul();
        Operator* div = new Div();
        cal = {{'+', add}, {'-', sub}, {'*', mul}, {'/', div}};
    }

    double calculate(double a, char op, double b) {
        return cal.at(op)->eval(a, b);
    }

    ~Calculator() {
        for (auto i : cal) {
            delete i.second;
        }
    }

    private:
        bool isEqual(double a, double b) const {
            return fabs(a-b) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
        }

        std::unordered_map<char, Operator*> cal;
};
```

Well, it does use the four basics of OOP, but is it really good? I have the following questions about the second code:

1. Does it really follow the `OCP`? (because I think we still need modify the code in `Calculator` if we add a new operator)
2. Doesn't it matter for introducing too many classes? 
   For example, if I write a tiny `git`, it would be many possible arguments like `init`, `commit` and so on. Should I prefer to introduce so many classes for possible commands, rather than just use the switch expression in the first code?
3. Is it the perfect solution to the problem? If not, what's the perfect design for it?

Comment: What "four basics of OOP" are you talking about?  And by OCP do you mean open/closed principle?

Comment: There is also the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) because simple is simply the most simple (sometimes).

Comment: Please be aware that your last question _"What's the perfect design"_ is very much an opinionated question, and as such is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. Also the number of `git` commands should **never** be a basis for how to write code --`git` is entirely orthogonal to software design.

Comment: @StephenNewell Four bascis of OOP means encapsulation, inheritance, abstraction and polymorphism. And OCP means open/closed principle

Comment: @Human-Compiler Sorry for the "perfect design" question, next time I won't ask such question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single perfect design for this. It's a tradeoff that you need to make based on what you expect to change more often and what guarantees the language provides for you. This is actually an old debate and you can find very comprehensive articles if you look up "pattern matching vs subtype polymorphism".

You may prefer the first approach (functional style), if you expect to have lots of `switch` statements giving new meanings to those operators, meanings that don't necessarily belong to the operator itself (in FP, behaviours don't really belong to types anyway). Think of stuff like:

```
double identityValue(char op) { switch (op) .... }
bool resultOverflows(double a, char op, N double b) { switch (op) ... }
```

However, when you add a new `Operator` type you'll have to change all these methods and you'll want the language to provide something like pattern matching, or at least to have compile-time checks for `case` exhaustion.

With the polymorphic approach, the behaviour stays with the type, so your operators will provide methods like `resultOverflows(double a, double b)`, `identityValue()` and so on. Adding a new Operator subtype will not affect any of the existing code using them (i.e. no need to add a new `case` everywhere, since you have no `switch` anywhere).

But when you add a new behaviour (another method, such as `identityValue()`, in case you find a need for it only later in your project), you'll have to change all the existing `Operator` subtypes out there.

---

For your use-case, I would go with the polymorphic approach for several reasons:

- it is the natural way to program in an OOP language like C++ (keep the data and behaviour together)
- there's no real support for pattern matching in C++, so the pseudo-functional approach is just difficult to maintain on the long run
- even in a language with better support for the functional approach (like Scala, or even Rust), you will often find it more natural to attach the behaviour to the types, especially when it reasonably belongs there, as I think it's the case with my examples above

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231092/is-pattern-matching-against-types-idiomatic-or-poor-design

Comment: https://medium.com/better-programming/pattern-matching-vs-polymorphism-ce0441fbfcda

Comment: Pattern matching isn't supported in c++/java, so is `switch` expression a better choice if we expect to have lots of cases?

Comment: I would say no, the natural approach for Java/C++ is the polymorphic one. But I don't really know what you mean by lots of classes: is that lots of places where you do `switch` or lots of Operator subtypes?

Comment: I added a recommendation to my answer, just to let you know what I would choose and why. But it may be biased, as the polymorphic approach comes naturally as the first option to me, disregarding the language support. In Java, I would most likely make this an `enum` type.

Answer (score 1):

First, its better to avoid direct usage of `new`/`delete` unless you **really** need them and you know what you are doing. In your case there is no need for them. Instead use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` accordingly.

Second, if you want to modify operation set without modification of `Calculator` class all you need to do is to provide a way to do it. E.g. function like this will suffice:

```
void Calculator::addOperator(char op, Operator *obj) {
    cal.insert({op, obj});
}
```

And this should answer your second question, since you can't do something similar with `switch`.